# Creating and interacting with background tasks in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a system that would manage a small database and populate it with data from the web.

I would like to have this process run in the background, but still have some way of interacting with it.

How can I go about this in Python?

I would like to know how to do this in two cases:

1. from within the same python script something like `daemon = task.start()` followed by `daemon.get_info()` or `daemon.do_something()`
2. from the shell (via another program I could make) `myclient get_info` or `myclient do_something`

Could someone give me some key concepts to go look into?

edit: I just read [this blogpost](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/), is socket programming (as indicated in his last example) the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I landed on some terminology that I was missing.
The core concept seems to be inter-process communication (ipc).

On unix variants the two easiest ways of implementing this are:

1. [Named Pipes](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) (one way communication)
2. [Sockets](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) (two way)

A python script that would make use of these could spawn another [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) which would repeatedly read from the pipe and communicate messages back to the main thread through a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/queue.html).